# Remove line breaks from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
UserInput = input("Input a number :")
Numbers = []
for index in range(int(UserInput)):
    print("Entry " + str(index+1) + " is ")
    Numbers.append(input())
```

I would like the output to look like this

```
Input a number :2
Entry 1 is 1
Entry 2 is 4
```

However I get the below using my current code - Python 3.6

```
Input a number :2
Entry 1 is 

1
Entry 2 is 

4
```

I guess I am missing something simple somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
UserInput = input("Input a number :")
Numbers = []
for index in range(int(UserInput)):
    Numbers.append(input("Entry " + str(index+1) + " is ")) # change here
```

Answer (score 0):

**With reference to your answer:-**

```
UserInput = input("Input a number :")
Numbers = []
for index in range(int(UserInput)):
    print("Entry " + str(index+1) + " is ",end='')
    Numbers.append(input())
```